# Problem with microphone of headset in recording sound in Windows XP

Tags: audio, headset

I have a headset that records on another computer with Windows XP but it doesn't record my voice on my laptop.

I have a sound card and can hear the sound but I can't record the sound. I checked the Control Panel - here is a screenshot, but I really don't know what the problem is. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What model is the laptop?

Comment: farasoo it is too old more than 7 years old

Comment: it has the socket that the picture of it is a microphone and I used it and connected to it but no result you think the problem is from hardware not software?

Comment: I was just wondering if it was going to be line in not mic.

Comment: I used the line of microphone I searched a lot on the internet I tried many possible solutions for recording also one part of setting it had test I used it but for mic it tells me your sound didn't detect something like this sentence.

Comment: I found the problem hahaha I am so happy very very happy OMG I went to properties and unselected 2 mics in advanced then I went to ctrl panel in audio tab of sounds and devices and in recording sound I checked the selected box:D huraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaay!